# Is there a way to display a SAS job the same way as a SAS stored process in the SAS Portal in 9.4?

Tags: sas, sas-visual-analytics

Currently, when I open a SAS job via SAS Drive, I always end up in the developer view. How do I make it so that when I open a SAS job in dirve that I only have to enter the parameters and start the job.
I've seen attempts to recreate the SAS portal through a website, but I'd rather there be a way to do it through the SAS Viya interface.

I tried using the SAS Job Execution Web Application but all i got out of that are URls to the SAS Jobs that get me my desired View that looks like this.

SAS Job

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

You will need to build an interface using HTML or the XML-based prompt language. See these examples: [Build an HTML Input Form](https://go.documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/v_033/jobexecug/n1ouf0rx7w615kn0z1thhmj4vcnj.htm#n1m61mjl56dl47n142co8gk6nhpo) and [Prompts](https://go.documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/v_033/jobexecug/n1ouf0rx7w615kn0z1thhmj4vcnj.htm#p16ohya5s1urz7n105qcuvj1ihra).

You can also read more about how to do this in the paper [Modernizing Scenario Analysis with SAS Viya and Visual Analytics](https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Global-Forum-Proceedings/Modernizing-Scenario-Analysis-With-SAS-Viya-and-SAS-Visual/ta-p/726348).

For example:

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        @font-face {
            font-family: AvenirNext;
            src: url("/SASJobExecution/images/AvenirNextforSAS.woff") format("woff");
        }
        
        body {
            font-family: AvenirNext, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
            -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
            text-align: center
        }
        
        .wrapper {
            padding-bottom: 10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="/SASJobExecution/" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="_program" value="$PROGRAM$"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="_action" value="execute,wait"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="$CSRF$"/>
                   
        <p><b>Enter a Pretzel Scenario</b></p>
            
        <div class="wrapper">
            <label>Price (USD) <input type="text" name="price" placeholder="2.49"/></label>
        </div>
            
        <div class="wrapper">
            <label>Cost (USD) <input type="text" name="cost" placeholder="0.25"/></label>
        </div>

        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"/> 
            
    </form>
</body>
```

This creates an input form that looks like this:

[image]